# Having Trouble Visualizing a T-Distribution in Python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I'm attempting to add a simple t-score visualization to some analysis utilities I'm writing (plotting scipy's `pdf` probability density function over an interval). In this example, I'm plotting a Student's t distribution, along with critical t-score cutoffs for a given problem set. However, the simple vis just isn't turning out correctly so far as I can tell.

In this example, I have an `n=24` dataset and I'm trying to visualize an `alpha=0.05` two tailed test for it (AKA statistical significance indicated by 2.5% in either tail of the distribution). I would expect the critical t-score to intersect the t-distribution at a y (probability) value of 0.025, but the t-distribution itself seems to be scaled/flattened? by some amount.

So far as I can tell, the t distribution just doesn't match up with what I would expect actual probabilities to be, but the setup is simple enough where I can't tell where I'm going wrong. I am somewhat new to statistics and am wondering if I'm missing something fundamental here?

```
## Basic T-Distribution
import scipy.stats as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

## Setup      
dof = 23        # Degrees of freedom
alpha = 0.05    # Significence level
ntails = 2      # Number of tails 

## Calculate critical t-score
tcrit = abs(st.t.ppf(alpha/ntails, dof))
# +=2.068

plt.figure()
xs = np.linspace(-10,10,1000)
plt.plot(xs, st.t.pdf(xs,dof), 'k', label="T-Distribution PDF")

## Plot some vertical lines representing critical t-score cutoff
critline = np.linspace(0,alpha/ntails)  # y range for critical line, AKA probability from 0-p*
xs_1 = len(critline) * [-tcrit]         # X ranges for plotting
xs_2 = len(critline) * [tcrit]
plt.plot(xs_1, critline, 'r', label="-t* for dof=23")
plt.plot(xs_2, critline,'r', label="t* for dof=23")
plt.legend()
```

[image: T-Vis]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF is a *density*. The Y axis is not in units of "probability" but "probability per unit of X". Evaluate the PDF at `tcrit` to get the appropriate value to match the curve.

Try this to plot the vertical lines:

```
plt.vlines([-tcrit, tcrit], 0.0, st.t.pdf(tcrit), colors='r')
```

Comment: +1 for `vlines`, thanks there and for the explination. I am confused by what a "unit of X" is here then? Isn't X the t-score, which is more or less a standardized measure of difference? How would you get rid of the "per unit of X" here to visualize true probability on a chart?

Comment: You don't get rid of it. The values of the PDF are still densities, not probabilities. The integral of the PDF is a function of probabilities, but that's not what you are plotting. The `alpha/2` is the *area* under the curve of each of the two tails, not the *value* of the PDF at those points.

Comment: Aah aah aah, that makes total sense now. Thank you for clarifying!

Comment: That's why I say "probability per unit of X". Even if, according to SI rules, X is unitless (and for that matter, so is "probability"), it helps my intuition to make up said units and apply some dimensional analysis.